# How can I alter this array so that it becomes this object structure in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I have the following `array` in PHP full of data.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 496 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 170 
        [stakeholder_id] => 96 
        [submission_sequence] => 41 
    ) [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 497 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 171 
        [stakeholder_id] => 96 
        [submission_sequence] => 42 
    ) [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 498 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 172 
        [stakeholder_id] => 96 
        [submission_sequence] => 43 
    ) [3] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 499 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 173 
        [stakeholder_id] => 96 
        [submission_sequence] => 
    ) [4] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 500 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 174 
        [stakeholder_id] => 97 
        [submission_sequence] => 41 
    ) [5] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 501 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 175 
        [stakeholder_id] => 97 
        [submission_sequence] => 42 
    ) [6] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 502 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 176 
        [stakeholder_id] => 97 
        [submission_sequence] => 43 
    ) [7] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 503 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 177 
        [stakeholder_id] => 97 
        [submission_sequence] => 
    ) [8] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 504 
        [debate_id] => 110 
        [student_id] => 178 
        [stakeholder_id] => 98 
        [submission_sequence] => 41 
    )
);
```

I would like this data to be presented as the following object..

```
Object ( 
    debate_id ( 
        stakeholder_id (
            Array (
                [0] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 
                    [student_id] =>
                    [submission_sequence] =>
                )
                [1] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 
                    [student_id] =>
                    [submission_sequence] =>
                )
                [2] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 
                    [student_id] =>
                    [submission_sequence] =>
                )
                [3] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 
                    [student_id] =>
                    [submission_sequence] =>
                )
            )
        )
        stakeholder_id (
            ...
        )
        stakeholder_id (
            ...
        )
        stakeholder_id (
            ...
        )
    ) 
);
```

How can I alter this array so that it becomes this object structure in PHP?

I wish to do this to increase it's readability and it's easier for me to read the data into my View from my Model (since I'm using the CodeIgniter framework)..

Comment: start with a loop

Comment: @nogad How would I start this loop?

Comment: `for()` or `foreach()`

Comment: Water into Wine you can do! But data transformation using a simple loop is beyond you! I knew it was just a fable

Comment: Can't understand your desired output format at all. Can you give an actual example?

Comment: Using numbers as the properties of an object is generally wrong. Are you sure that's what you really want, and not an associative array?